# How can I keep nodejs running even after crash on Ubuntu

Tags: nodejs

Is there any way I can run the nodejs program app.js always in the server even it crash? So I do not need to keep restarting node app.js by nohup

Comment: This question is generally known as the Halting Problem. In any case, it has nothing to do with Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not related to ethereum at all. Try using [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for your nodejs, there is auto starting option for nodejs applications.

Comment: Which is why the question is nominated to be closed. Also, it is stated in a comment to the question from about 4 hours ago.

Comment: I written an ethereum script in node but it always crash after some time, can I use PM2 to restart it automatically? I checked the commands on PM2 but the only restart it when the file is modified it does not specify whe the file crash or stop.